# Terraform access map

Tags: terraform, maps

I am trying to access all groups and create groups in the below terraform code. But I am facing error  This object does not have an attribute named "groups". Is there any logic I am missing here in the resource "og" "example"
for_each=toset(flatten(local.instances[*].groups)). Thanks

```
locals {
  instances = {
    test1 = {
    baseUrl   = "url1"
    subDomain = "sd1"
    groups = [
      "app1",
      "app2",
    ],
    }
    test2 = {
    baseUrl   = "url2"
    subDomain = "sd2"
    groups = [
      "t1",
      "t2",
    ],
    }
  }
}
resource "og" "example" {
  for_each    = toset(flatten(local.instances[*].groups))
  name        = each.value
  description = "${each.value}-access"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local variable is a map, not a list. So it should be:

```
for_each    = toset(flatten(values(local.instances)[*].groups))
```